# Variable names with dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

Python beginner here. A question about dictionaries.

My input is a variable length list (eg a = ['eggs', 'ham', 'bacon'...] ) which functions as a list of search terms to be used on an imported CSV file.

I have defined four functions that match each term to various values from said CSV file. So, each input term will result in four lists of results.

I would like to store the input terms as a key in a dictionary (easy enough) and the resulting four lists as values (also easy enough).

However, because the input list is of variable length I would like to set up a function to define and name the dictionaries 'term1', 'term2', illustrated very basically thus:

```
term1 = { 'eggs' : [[list1] , [list2] , [list3] , [list4]] }
term2 = { 'ham' : [[list1] , [list2] , [list3] , [list4]] }
term3 = { 'bacon' : [[list1] , [list2] , [list3] , [list4]] }
```

Is there a) a way to name dictionaries like this?; and b) AND have them be globally available? If so, how? Any and all help very much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you define one dictionary with all the data in it? It will be much easier to manipulate it and access its values.

Comment: Your sample isn't valid Python. You've got one key with multiple values, which is a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @Joe no it isn't. Did you miss the outer brackets on the values? They are each a list of lists. I can paste the code into an interpreter (provided I defined list1..list4) and Python parses it just fine.

Comment: When @Joe posted, the [list1], etc. lists weren't themselves enclosed within a list, the outer brackets were added later. (SO keeps the edit history, click on the link above after the word "edited".)

Answer (score 4):

Not an approach I'd recommend, but you can access both the local and global namespaces as dictionaries; e.g. you can add arbitrary variables to those namespaces using the familiar dict interface:

```
>>> globals()['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> foo
'bar'
>>> locals()['spam'] = 'eggs'
>>> spam
'eggs'
```

You *will* run into naming conflicts though. Also, how will the rest of your code know what global variables contain your results? They'll have to do indirect look-ups too!

You better just use **one** dictionary containing your results, and let that be the namespace instead of the global namespace.

Comment: Why a -1 vote? I did say that the OP really doesn't want to do this if they can help it.

Comment: Downvote tooltip reads "This answer is not useful".  It wasn't my downvote, but I would question the usefulness (or even the utility) of an answer that starts with "Not an approach I'd recommend..." - why post in the first place then?  Especially since the OP's situation isn't anywhere near an edge case that might warrant the method you describe.

Comment: Modifying locals() is forbidden http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: @gnibbler: "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified" does not mean 'forbidden'. It's not a good idea, certainly.

Comment: why would you give *really* bad advice and not expect downvotes?

Comment: @Paul: It does answer the question "How do I add entries to the global or local namespace". The premise of the question may be incorrect, but it can still be answered.

Comment: @Corey: I stated how you could do the bad thing the question was asking for, then told them not to do that but something else instead. I never advised that altering the global or local namespace is a good idea.

Comment: @Martin: up/down votes are an indicator of useful or not, regardless of whether the answer is an answer, or even a correct one. That's why no one upvotes trivial answers that just re-echo the posted exception text - yes the answer is correct, but probably not too useful.

Comment: @Martijn, It's not just because it looks ugly - Modifying locals() doesn't always work. I can't find a counterexample at this moment, but I have seen it happen for sure.

Comment: @gnibbler I understood thtat :-) Modifying locals() is at your own risk and don't come crying to Guido when it comes back to bite you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this :

```
results = {}
for name in ['eggs', 'ham', 'bacon']:
   results[name] = (function1(name), function2(name), function3(name), function4(name),)
```

where functionX are your functions that will return the listX result from CSV file or whatever.

Here you will have in the results dictionnary something like this :

```
results = { 
   'eggs' : (egg_list1, egg_list2, egg_list3, egg_list4), 
   'ham' : (ham_list1, ham_list2, ham_list3, ham_list4),
   'bacon' : (bacon_list1, bacon_list2, bacon_list3, bacon_list4),
}
```

Comment: If each function reads over the CSV file, then this file will get processed `(number of keys) X (number of functions)` times. Sometimes this can't be helped, but often there is an orthogonal approach that reads the CSV file only once, and updates values in the results dict as you go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you might pre-initialize your one dictionary containing all data:

```
a = "eggs bacon ham".split()
summary = dict((key,([],[],[],[])) for key in a)

for lineno,line in enumerate(csv_file):
    # first element in the line is assumed to be the key ("eggs", "bacon", etc.)
    key = line[0]
    # update the data values for this key
    summary[key][0].append(lineno)
    summary[key][1].append(something_else)
    # ... etc.
```

I find this kind of indexed access a bit fragile though, and prefer keyed or attribute access. Your hardcoded list of 4 lists may be better represented as a dict or even objects of some simple data-tallying class.

Also, I think your "eggs", "bacon", and "ham" list will grow over time, as you find entries in your CSV file for "pancakes", "waffles", "hash browns" and so on. I have gotten to use defaultdict's more and more lately for tallying up data as I go through data files or database tables.  Instead of pre-defining what keys I expect to get (and having to update the list myself when the input data gets new values added to it), defaultdict just adds new entries of the form I define:

```
class Tally(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.lines = []
        self.values = []

from collections import defaultdict
summary = defaultdict(Tally)

for lineno,line in enumerate(csv_file):
    # first element in the line is assumed to be the key ("eggs", "bacon", etc.)
    key = line[0]
    # update the data values for this key
    summary[key].count += 1
    summary[key].lines.append(lineno)
    summary[key].values.append(line[1])
    # ... etc.
```

defaultdict saves me the cumbersome and repetitive "if key not in summarydict: add new entry..." overhead, so my code stays fairly clean.

Comment: This is a little advanced for me at this stage, but I managed to adapt your technique and get it to work. Thanks for the help.